# Morphia query for finding an element where a field has a null value

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I'm struggling to create a Morphia query (using the typed query class `Query<T>`) to implement the following:

```
db.getCollection('Order').find({'orderLines.trackingDetails': {$elemMatch: {deliveryDate: {$exists: false}}}})
```

The struggle is how to code for the {$exists: false} (to return only records where the trackingDetails has an element where deliveryDate does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
.add("orderLines.trackingDetails",
        new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",
          new BasicDBObject("deliveryDate",
            new BasicDBObject("$exists", false))))
.get();

Query<Order> q = datastore.createQuery(Order.class, query);
```